# Google Analytics on SharePoint Online (when viewing documents)

Tags: sharepoint-online, document, word, web-analytics, google-analytics

We are using Google Analytics to track some metrics in our SharePoint Online environment.

Does anyone know a way to get Google Analytics to pick up on when a document is being viewed using Word Online / Excel Online / PowerPoint Online?

The documents open in a new frame (WopiFrame.aspx) that does not use our custom master page which has the Google Analytics tracking code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this would not be possible.  Those pages do not use the master page and the only way to get custom code to those is with an App for Office.  Those, however, wouldn't load the Google Analytics tracking code on every page request.  If this were on-premise, you could do some custom stuff in IIS to make it happen.  But there isn't anything you can do with SPO/Office365.

Comment: Thanks John, any experience or recommendations (outside of google) to capture that kind of information.

In particular trying just trying to figure out who looked at which files.

Comment: Google Analytics "In-Page Analytics" will show you where people clicked on a page.  That might be something to tie into (not sure how difficult that would be).  I'm not all that familiar with other analytics systems, but finding out which links were clicked on the pages that the tracking code is loaded is about the only way I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that Adrian Fiechter's *Google Analytics for SharePoint 2013 / Office 365* .wsp solution works on WopiFrame.aspx pages.  http://googleanalytics365.codeplex.com/